# how to implement multiauth in laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, jwt

I have two users admin/user i want to authenticate this two users for api,
it is working for one user but its not working for admin

see what i have tried
in admin controller

```
public function login(Request $request){

//        $res=;
   // dd ($res);
     if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' =>  $request->email, 'password' =>  $request->password]))
    {

  // if successful, then redirect to their intended location


        $user = auth()->guard('admin')->user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('admin')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised','email'=> $request->email,'password'=> $request->password], 401);
    }
}
```

and in api.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {

Route::post('login', 'API\Admin\AdminController@login')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('register', 'API\Admin\AdminController@register')->name('admin.register');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin-api'], function(){
 Route::post('get-details', 'API\Admin\AdminController@getDetails');
});


});
```

When i try to call attempt function for admin its giving me error

> BadMethodCallException
>   Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.

can you please share your ideas over how to do multiauth in laravel/passport

Comment: I tried a similar way of authenticating both users but I failed, so instead I added an enum "type" field to my users table.

Comment: so there is no way of doing multiauth for api in laravel/passport?

Comment: check this repo out https://github.com/sfelix-martins/passport-multiauth

Comment: ok will check that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can implement multiauth in laravel passport you have to follow below steps

1) create 4 guards in my situation i created like

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
     ],
     'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
     'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],
```

then when logging that type of user in controller make sure you are using sessio driver guards like

usercontroller.php

```
 public function login(){
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

in admincontroller.php

```
 public function login(){
    if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
        $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('admin')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

and when checking the token use the passport driver guard like

```
public function getDetails()
{
    $user = Auth::guard('admin-api')->user();
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
}
```

and in middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
 Route::post('admin/get-details', 'API\Admin\AdminController@getDetails');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it through middleware, hopefully, this will help you - [Laravel Passport Multiple Authentication using Guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851208/laravel-passport-multiple-authentication-using-guards)