# Laravel passport api token works for all

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

Using `passport` on `Laravel 6` and it work fine with `users` now I want to set `passport` for `admins` I called agents here. So I did in this way (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449524/9158178)):

```
Route::middleware('auth:agent')->group(function () {
```

Controller:

```
return Auth::guard('agent')->user();
```

And auth.php:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'agent' => [
            'driver'   => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'agents',
        ],
    ],

...

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'agents' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Agent::class,
        ],
    ],
```

So I logged as user, and set api token and run this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this-> successStatus);
```

This return me user details and working fine then I logged as admin with same token, and run:

```
return Auth::guard('agent')->user();
```

It return me agent details too! with same `api_token` that I used for `users`. I tested all with `postman`. It should not retrun agent details with users token, also on the contrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while I didn't get any answer, tried to solve this issue on my own, I searched a lot and none of available solution work for me. I decided to use `token` as `driver` ([basic Laravel auth](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)) for admin users *(agents)*

So I changed:

```
    'agent' => [
        'driver'   => 'token', // change passport to token
        'provider' => 'agents',
        'hash' => true,
    ],
```

And according that article made `api_token` column and that solved my issue. I think there is no change to solve this issue by `passport`, you need to set `token` or `session` to get this.