# using both regular authentication and http basic authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I want to have authentication via HTTP Basic Auth --and-- authentication which accepts a username / password via HTML. I also want the username / password combo to be different for each one. To that end I figured I'd use the following pre-built middleware:

- Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate
- Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/AuthenticateWithBasicAuth

My question is...  can I use both regular authentication authentication and HTTP Basic authentication at the same time whilst having a different username / password combo for both?

Comment: Have you tried it? Should be pretty quick to just enable both middleware and see if it works. Your users are going to love you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/laravel-middleware-basic-auth-implementation-88b777361b5c pointed me in the necessary direction. Basically, per that tutorial, Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/AuthenticateWithBasicAuth was *not* used. A new from-scratch middleware was created and then added to app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: You should extract the instructions from the linked aricle in case the viewer of the answer cannot access medium or the original author deletes the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your question may be solved using multiauth and Laravel Passport, see here for more info:

[how to implement multiauth in laravel passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445237/how-to-implement-multiauth-in-laravel-passport)